# liferay error hook deployment

Tags: jboss, liferay, hook

I have a problem with the deployment of a custom hook in liferay. When the server (jboss) is on and I build the hook, there are no problems. But when I restart the server, I get the follow error:

```
ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to ClassLoader: name=vfsfile...
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parent domain: liferay.com does not exist.
```

I'm thinking of deploying the parent first, but I have no idea how.  I also don't know who is the parent.

I'm using hot-deploy and I got the problem only when i restart the server.   but when I build it with server on it correctly works.

```
Error :
Error creating classloader for vfsfile:/C:/Users/XXXXX/MMMMMM/bundles/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/YYYYYYY-hook.war/
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractDeploymentContext.createClassLoader(AbstractDeploymentContext.java:579)
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractDeploymentUnit.createClassLoader(AbstractDeploymentUnit.java:161)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractClassLoaderDeployer.deploy(AbstractClassLoaderDeployer.java:53)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Parent domain: liferay.com does not exist.**
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.ClassLoaderSystem.registerClassLoaderPolicy(ClassLoaderSystem.java:389)
    at org.jboss.classloading.spi.dependency.policy.ClassLoaderPolicyModule.registerClassLoaderPolicy(ClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:131)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.classloading.AbstractLevelClassLoaderSystemDeployer.createClassLoader(AbstractLevelClassLoaderSystemDeployer.java:120)
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractDeploymentContext.createClassLoader(AbstractDeploymentContext.java:565)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: How are you deploying the hook? Are you doing it through hot-deploy or through market place?

Comment: Please include complete error logs.